# Searching for Unicode chars from a raw byte array - Free Pascal\Lazarus or Delphi

Tags: delphi, unicode, arrays, freepascal

I don't want to bore people with the explanation of why and how so I 'll just jump right in.

I have an array of bytes containing raw byte data. The array is 1000 bytes. I want to go through that array of 1000 bytes and extract UTF-16 Unicode characters only that might resemble a filename but I don't know where, exactly, in that array of 1000 bytes the characters appear.

I have read 
[Lazarus Unicode Page](http://wiki.freepascal.org/LCL_Unicode_Support) and [this](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) but am still somewhat unsure with the syntactical approach to my problem. I understand that a Unicode char can be up to 4 bytes in size but is commonly two (a letter and a space).

I have used UTF8encode(WideCharLenToString(@MyArray,SomeIntValue) with success for other areas where I KNOW certain Unicode chars exist further to [this thread](http://www.lazarus.freepascal.org/index.php/topic,16662.msg90928.html#msg90928) that I asked about and is now solved. But I now need to "hunt" for them now, for a different reason, within the array. e.g. "*Look at the first 16 bytes. Are they Unicode? If not, Look at the next 16. Are they Unicode? If so, convert them to a string and display them"*.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 5):

Without knowing the actual layout of the bytes, or the formatting of the filename (does it have a drive letter and path, does it use UNC paths, or is it just a file name by itself?), hunting for the boundaries of the filename string is going to be difficult.

If you can assume that the filename always begins with a drive letter and path, then you can loop through the array one byte a time until you decode a six-byte UTF-16 sequence that consists of a character between `'a'`-`'z'` or `'A'`-`'Z'` followed by `':'` and `'\'` characters.  If you find that, keep decoding UTF-16 sequences until you encounter a decoded null character or a binary value that is not a valid UTF-16 sequence, eg:

```
var
  Buffer: array[0..1000-1] of Byte;
  I: Integer;
  PCh: PWord;
  Hi, Lo: Word;
  Ch: Cardinal;
  PStart: PWideChar;
  Len: Integer;
  FileName: WideString;
begin
  ...

  I := 0;
  while I <= (SizeOf(Buffer)-6) do
  begin
    PCh := PWord(@Buffer[I]);
    if not (((PCh^ >= Ord('a')) and (PCh^ <= Ord('z'))) or ((PCh^ >= Ord('A')) and (PCh^ <= Ord('Z')))) then
    begin
      Inc(I);
      Continue;
    end;
    Inc(PCh);    
    if PCh^ <> Ord(':') then
    begin
      Inc(I);
      Continue;
    end;
    Inc(PCh);
    if PCh^ <> Ord('\') then
    begin
      Inc(I);
      Continue;
    end;
    PStart := PWideChar(@Buffer[I]);
    Len := 0;
    Inc(I, 6);
    Inc(PCh);
    while I <= (SizeOf(Buffer)-2) do
    begin
      if (PCh^ < $D800) or (PCh^ > $DFFF) then
      begin
        Ch := Cardinal(PCh^);
        Inc(I, 2);
        if Ch = 0 then Break;
        Inc(Len);
      end else
      begin
        if PCh^ > $DBFF then Break;
        if (I+2) = SizeOf(Buffer) then Break;
        Hi := PCh^;
        Inc(PCh);
        if (PCh^ < $DC00) or (PCh^ > $DFFF) then Break;
        Lo := PCh^;
        Ch := ((Cardinal(Hi) - $D800) * $400) + (Cardinal(Lo) - $DC00) + $10000;
        if Ch > $10FFFF then Break;
        Inc(I, 4);
        Inc(Len, 2);
      end;
    end;
    SetString(FileName, PStart, Len);
    if Len > 0 then
    begin
      ... use FileName as nedeed...
    end;
  end;
  ...
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

UTF-16 codepoints are either 2 bytes or 4 bytes long. It's not a letter and a space; in isolation, most 16-bit words are valid UTF-16 characters. (Codepoints with values between D800 and DBFF need to be followed by a value in the range DC00-DFFF to make one complete Unicode character.) If you're just looking for valid UTF-16, it's unlikely you'll make much headway. You'll need to look specific patterns found in filenames, like .ext (which would be encoded in UTF-16 as either \00.\00e\00x\00t or .\00e\00x\00t\00, depending on whether it's big-endian or little-endian.)